# How to investigate ping loss with strong signal

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, interference

I have a new build with an Intel 8265 Wifi adapter. I am experiencing considerable connectivity loss (local gateway ping loss of around 50%), even though the signal is reported to be above 50% strength (45/70). Thinking that the problem could have been related to the NIC, I bought an ALFA AWUS036AC adapter (rtl8812au), which is showing a similar behaviour. No other devices are showing the same problem, even when operated nearby the NICs that I have mentioned. Before the new build, I used to work on my laptop which was located roughly in the same spot on the desk where the desktop PC is now and I never had this problem.

How can I determine whether it is an interference problem or something software-related (e.g. congested TCP traffic on the host)?

[Here's a PC Part Picker link with my build's specs.](http://pcpartpicker.com/user/P403n1x87/builds/#view=3FHhP6)

Comment: This is probably the first thing you tried, but have you power cycled the router? When you do, does the problem reappear immediately? What about when you power cycle your rig? If any of this fixes the problem, even if temporarily, the issue is likely somehow software-related.

Comment: Also, can you try moving your rig closer to the router? If that does not help, we've eliminated interference in the wireless connection as the culprit.

Comment: Power cycling the devices involved doesn't seem to provide any improvements. Unfortunately it's not easy for me to move the rig closer too the router. In the end they are separated by two walls and a distance of 4 meters top.

Comment: Hmmm... Any way you can move the rig around the room and see if the signal strength changes at all?

Comment: No but I can move the antennas of the two NICs and the signal strength stays above 50%. For example, this is what iwconfig reports: Link Quality=87/100  Signal level=100/100  Noise level=0/100

Comment: Sounds to me like this isn't an interference issue. Could I get some more information on your build's specs? My gut tells me this may be a hardware or driver issue.

Comment: Here you go: https://pcpartpicker.com/user/P403n1x87/builds/#view=3FHhP6

Comment: Things to look at: `iw station dump` to see what the NICs think of the current connection quality/error, `dmesg` output for strange error/reassociations etc., `iw scan` to see if there's other APs on the same channel (keep in mind that several channels are used for each AP depending on the connection mode, e.g. 802.11g channel 3 will use channels 1-5). You can also play around with an aluminum foil etc., put it between the antennas and the computer or in other places and see if anything changes.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to use the dump command with iw. I would rule out any channel issues as other devices (phone, tablet, laptop) work fine with the same AP on both 2.4 and 5 GHz. The output of dmesg doesn't show any frequent associations to the AP (i.e. the NIC stays associated with the AP even when the ping loss occurs).